# How to resume xsl number count after nesting and while using level="any"

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to have the `<xsl:number/>` resume its counter. However, since it is using `level="any"`, it counts its previous sibling's child elements, which is undesirable.

Using the sample code below, everything looks correct except for the list items containing `Three` and `Four`. Those items are given the number counts of 5 and 6 because the counter is using the items nested within item `Two` instead of continuing from where item `Two` itself left off.

Sample Input XML:

```
<body>
    <div class="list-wrapper">
        <ol>
            <li>One</li>
            <li><span>Two</span>
                <ol>
                    <li>AAA</li>
                    <li>BBB</li>
                </ol>
                <div class="list-wrapper">
                    <ol>
                        <li>CCC</li>
                        <li>DDD</li>
                    </ol>
                    <ol>
                        <li>EEE</li>
                        <li>FFF</li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
                <ol>
                    <li>GGG</li>
                    <li>HHH</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <ol>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="list-wrapper">
        <ol>
            <li>Five</li>
            <li>Six</li>
        </ol>
        <ol>
            <li>Seven</li>
            <li>Eight</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>
```

Sample Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <fo:root>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='list-wrapper']">
        <fo:list-block>
            <xsl:apply-templates  mode="list-wrapper" />
        </fo:list-block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ol" mode="list-wrapper">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="list-wrapper" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li" mode="list-wrapper">
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label>
                <xsl:number format="1." count="div[@class='list-wrapper']/ol/li" from="div[@class='list-wrapper']" level="any" />
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ol">
        <fo:list-block>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:list-block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li">
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label>
                <xsl:number format="1."/>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to simplify the template by replacing the `for-each` with an `apply-templates`.

This solution appears best.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <fo:root>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='list-wrapper']">
        <fo:list-block>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ol/li" />
        </fo:list-block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ol">
        <fo:list-block>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:list-block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ol/li">
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label>
                <xsl:number format="1." value="position()" />
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I can get around the nesting problem by using an `xsl:for-each` to handle only the direct children of `div[@class='list-wrapper']`.

Now I can simply use `position()` to number each node as I require.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <fo:root>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div[@class='list-wrapper']">
        <fo:list-block>
            <xsl:for-each select="ol/li">
                <xsl:call-template name="process-ordered-list" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:list-block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li">
        <xsl:call-template name="process-ordered-list" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="process-ordered-list">
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label>
                <xsl:number format="1." value="position()" />
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </fo:list-item-body>
        </fo:list-item>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ol">
        <fo:list-block>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:list-block>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```